# How to enter specific values in a new column in EXCEL based on the values of another existing column

Tags: excel, dataset

I'm working with a dataset containing gamelogs of all MLB teams. The data is ordered by date but I want to add new data based on the home team. How can I add specific values to a new column (in my case, income per capita in home team's metropolitan area) based on the who the home team is? For example if Baltimore's per capita income is $60,000, how do I automatically enter 60,000 for all 81 home games of the Baltimore Orioles and then repeat the process for all other teams? The name of the home team is contained in Column G. The shorthand for Baltimore Orioles in this column is BAL.

Comment: From where are you getting the income per capita?

Comment: From the census bureau.

Comment: If you get the "extra" information into a new sheet, with the shorthand name, you could do a simple vlookup?